# Are questions of champion viability allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are questions pertaining to champion builds' viability, for MOBA's, on-topic? I.E. Is Master Yi viable when built AP in League of Legends?(No need to answer, just an example.)

I know there is a lot of different ways to ask this, but I'm pretty much saying are questions like this allowed:

- Is (champ), built as (build-type), viable?
- What teams would (champ), built as (build-type), mesh with?
- What position would (champ) play, when built as (build-type)

If any of those three aren't on-topic, please tell. I have at least two or three like those, and I don't want them all to be closed D:

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Hmmm... Yes, that's very true...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see any particular problem with them.

- It's true they are subjective, but so is every strategy- or build-related question.
- They depend on the current meta-game - but that's also true for many questions of other games, for example those related to Starcraft II multiplayer.
- The answer might change on the next version, but that also applies to many other frequently-updated games such as Minecraft or Diablo III.

Do try to narrow your scope if possible, though - **focus on the specific problems you are trying to solve and decisions you need to take, rather than just asking general questions about what is "considered good" and "considered bad".**

"Champ X sucks at Y, how can I make up for or mitigate that?" is *much* better than "Is Champ X viable?"

Comment: Yay we agree on something!

Comment: `focus on the specific problems you are trying to solve` is the biggest thing IMO.  "Champ X sucks at Y, how can I make up for or mitigate that?" is much better than "Is Champ X viable?"

Comment: Okay, so they are on-topic as long as they are specific enough. Thanks for the help guys. Should I put a "status-completed" tag on this now?

Comment: @JonnyB "status-whatever" are moderator-only tags, and in any case are mainly used for things like bug reports or feature requests, not general discussions.

Comment: @Oak Oh, okay .