# Controversial questions, what does the average user do?

Tags: discussion

I was on the site today, and I noticed [this recent question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/128984/25368) get closed as "primarily opinion-based".

However, when I was browsing through unanswered questions for the same game, I found [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/127307/25368) which was also one of those 'close-to-opinion' types.
This second question had been closed before, but given a new title and reopened.
Currently it is open and the title is `"Is Wukong a viable champion?"`.
The first question is closed, it's title is `"Is Evelynn viable anymore? [on hold]"`.

Both questions highlight some of the champion's strengths and basically ask "Why is this champion not viable?"

Now, both have answers but neither have accepted answers.  They both have little discussions in the comments, and [this meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7518/25368) was linked from the second question's closure.

I'm just not sure what to do, I know it can't be right, having one question closed and the other open, when they are both the same question with only one changing variable.
I don't have enough rep to start a vote to close or re-open questions.
So I was wondering if the community could tell me:
 **as an average user of this site, what do I do when I come to something controversial like this?**

Do I flag it for mod attention? If so, do I need to flag both questions?
Do I comment with links to the other question? But I don't want to 'spam' the comments section.

I'd like to be able to do something, rather than have it sit there and cause confusion because no one knows what to do.
If anyone could provide an answer as to what the average user could do in a situation like this, that would be perfect.  And if they could recommend what to do now, based on the general things-to-do in this situation, that would be even better.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the first question asks us for opinions on whether the user should play the character. It doesn't ask about viability so that the user can make the decision for themselves. Since *we* can't possibly know what the user should do, the only answers possible are personal opinion; since personal opinion is not acceptable as an answer, questions that can only be answered with unacceptable answers are off topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie should probably make that an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag it as needing mod attention and move on. When you get more rep and more experience with how such issues are handle (by reading the meta site or by just observation over time) you should be able to act appropriately.

For this specific case, champ viability question are not off topic, but should focus on solving a specific problem instead of being theoretical in nature.  [Are questions of champion viability allowed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6788/are-questions-of-champion-viability-allowed?lq=1)